# AtD ruby library - Unexpected response code from AtD service: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http-status-code-503

I am using a relatively recent Ruby library within my Rails (3.2) app which integrates the "After The Deadline" API. The library has two methods that I am passing within the "create" action of a controller which call on the AtD API:

```
AfterTheDeadline.stats(@table.textcolumn)
AfterTheDeadline.check(@table.textcolumn)
```

It ends up being the case that when you pass these two calls in rapid succession, the AtD API has some sort of rate limit (which I didn't know about), yielding the following error:

```
Unexpected response code from AtD service: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

Anyway, I'm asking this question in order to answer immediately in case anyone has the same problem in the future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the kind help of the Gem author, the solution to the problem (some sort of rate limit set inconspicuously by the AtD service) is to add `sleep(1)` before the check call.